# Finding substring with multiple arguments in loop query sql

Tags: sqlite

I want to intersect two or more results from a query from a for loop

My code takes in strings from the command line and checks the database for movies with matching actors that contain the substring

movie database

id | title

actor database

id | name

acting

movie_id | actor_id

Below is the code for getting the movies with one actor

```
inp = sys.argv[1]

query = 
'''
SELECT m.title 
FROM movie m
JOIN acting ag on m.id = ag.movie_id
JOIN actor a on a.id = ag.actor_id
WHERE a.name like '%' || ? || '%'
'''

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query, (inp,))
for tup in cur.fetchall:
    print(tup[0])
```

This program would get all the movies with actor with David in their name

```
./program "David'

The Secret Life of Pets
The Big Short
Concussion
A Most Violent Year 
Baggage Claim
Skyfall 
Drive 
Albert Nobbs 
The Simpsons Movie
```

I want to extend my program to take in multiple arguments, taking in multiple names of actors, where the actors act in the same movie.

Possible code?

```
for index in range(len(sys.argv - 1)):
    # insert code here
```

I think I should use an intersection of the outputs of the queries, but I don't know how to do that.

This is the output of movies that both Albert and David

```
./program "Albert" "David"
A Most Violent Year 
Baggage Claim 
The Simpsons Movie
```

But also

```
./program "Alb" "Dav" 
A Most Violent Year 
Baggage Claim 
The Simpsons Movie
```

Comment: What if "Alb" matches "Albert" and "Alberta" and "Dav" matches "David" and "Davy"? Do you want the common movies for all 4 actors?

Comment: Yes, it would match all movies that have Albert, Alberta, David and Davy

Answer (score 0):

First, you must pass to your query all the arguments as a comma separated list.
Then a recursive CTE will split the arguments and filter from the table `actor` only the rows that match the arguments.
Finally you will join the results of the filter to the tables `acting` and `movie` and aggregate with the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
query = """
WITH 
  params AS (
    SELECT '' name, ? ||',' list 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT SUBSTR(list, 1, INSTR(list, ',') - 1),
           SUBSTR(list, INSTR(list, ',') + 1)
    FROM params 
    WHERE list <> ''
  ),
  names AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
    FROM actor a INNER JOIN params p
    ON a.name LIKE '%' || p.name || '%' 
    WHERE p.name <> ''
  )
SELECT m.name 
FROM movie m
JOIN acting ag ON m.id = ag.movie_id
JOIN names n ON n.id = ag.actor_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names) 
"""

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query, (','.join(sys.argv[1:]),))
for tup in cur.fetchall():
    print(tup[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, however it seems to only work with certain substrings. ```./program "chris evans"``` and ```./program "chris eva"``` works but ```./program "chris ev"``` doesn't work and neither does any string shorter than that.

Comment: @MichaelQiao it works for any string. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1e845a1454fb5ac42d099a5411c26a00 "chris ev" is 1 argument so it returns all the common movies for all the matching actors it finds. If there are 2 actors with names that contain "Chris Ev" do they have any common movies?